# Choice sets in "thick" sets of sets

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set and let ${\cal S} \subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ be a collection of non-empty subsets of $X$. We say $C\subseteq X$ is a *choice set* for ${\cal S}$ if for all $s\in S$ we have $|s\cap C| = 1$. As [Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4600/bj%c3%b8rn-kjos-hanssen) pointed out, [choice sets do not always exist](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285451/8628).

Is there an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ and ${\cal S} \subseteq {\cal P}(\kappa)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ such that

1. for all $x\in\kappa$ we have $|\{s\in {\cal S}: x\in s\}| = \kappa$, every member of ${\cal S}$ has cardinality $\kappa$, and
2. there is a choice set $C\subseteq \kappa$ for ${\cal S}$

?

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want? Seems easy: one has to construct functions $f_\alpha:\kappa\to\kappa$ ($\alpha<\kappa$) such that each $f_\alpha$ attains 0 at exactly one point and for any pair $(\xi,\eta)\in \kappa\times \kappa$ there are $\kappa$ many $f_\alpha$ such that $f_\alpha(\xi)=\eta$. This can be done by bookkeeping.

Comment: Thanks...! Should I delete the question or do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: @Péter: Isn't it easier to consider the tail segments of the ordinal $\kappa+1$, with the exception of $\{\kappa\}$, with the choice set being just $\{\kappa\}$ itself?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\kappa$ be any infinite cardinal.

> Let $\cal S=\{\kappa\setminus\{x\}:0<x<\kappa\}$ and $C=\{0\}$.

Then all the given conditions are satisfied.

Comment: (This solution was inspired by @AsafKaraglia's comment from November 9.)