# Choice sets and the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set. We say ${\cal C} \subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ is a *cover* if $\bigcup {\cal C} = X$. A subset $D\subseteq X$ is a *choice set* for ${\cal C}$ if $|D\cap c| = 1$ for all $c\in C$.

[Ramiro de la Vega](https://mathoverflow.net/users/17836/ramiro-de-la-vega) showed in his [nice post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285702/8628) that

> > (S): every cover has a subcover that admits a choice set.

He used the Axiom of Choice to well-order the members of the cover and construct a subcover with a choice set.

**Question.** Does the statement (S) above imply the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: The assertion "every family of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets has a choice set" is well known to be equivalent to the axiom of choice, in fact, I think it used to be the standard formulation of the axiom of choice. Of course, if $\mathcal C$ is a family of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets, then $\mathcal C$ is a cover of $\bigcup\mathcal C$ with no proper subcover.

Comment: To be precise, according to [Patrick Suppes](https://books.google.nl/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Axiomatic+set+theory&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59YOTvLvXAhWSDOwKHe5dBp4Q6wEIJzAA#v=snippet&q=zermelo&f=false), Zermelo stated AC as: "every set of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets has a choice set"... But it's interesting history, of which I was unaware.  (Apart from the history I'm naturally biased of course to consider the answer below both shorter and more to the point, you can blame my ego for that :-))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P\subseteq X\times Y$ be sets such that $\forall x\in X\exists y\in Y[(x,y)\in P]$. We wish to derive from (S) the existence of an $f\subseteq P$ such that $\forall x\in X\exists! y\in Y[(x,y)\in f]$.

Consider the following cover of $P$. Let $
\cal{C}$ $:= \{\{(x,y)|y\in Y, (x,y)\in P\}|x\in X\}$. Notice that any subcover of $\cal{C}$ has to be $\cal{C}$ itself.

Let $f$ be a choice set for $\cal{C}$, then trivially $f\subseteq P$ and $\forall x\in X\exists! y\in Y[(x,y)\in f]$.